# In AWS Cognito, it is recommended not to call /oauth2/token from a browser. Why?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm currently working on a new project and using AWS Cognito to handle the authentication side of things.

We are currently using the authorization code flow for oauth2.

One part of the AWS Cognito documentation is being interpreted differently by different developers on the team, namely this clause:

> The `/oauth2/token` endpoint only supports `HTTPS POST`. Your app makes
> requests to this endpoint directly, not through the user's browser.

^ from [AWS Cognito - Token Endpoint Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html)

My question is: why shouldn't the `/oauth2/token` endpoint be called from a browser? I have assumed that they don't want it called from the browser for a reason, but I'm struggling with the *why*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GET V POST**

There is a basic answer to your question and a deeper one. The AWS docs perhaps mean that a browser GET cannot be used to access the token endpoint. Instead you need to make an HTTP POST from JavaScript code. The request does not contain a client secret since the JavaScript app is a public client.

**XSS THREATS**

Calling the token endpoint from a browser is not recommended for security reasons, since it involves returning tokens to the browser. In the event of a cross site scripting exploit, the threats are articulated in [Philippe De Rycks's video](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html) from a few years ago.

**STRONGER COOKIES**

Meanwhile, in the last few years, browser HTTP-only cookies have become stronger, due to the [RFC6265bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/) enhancements to cookies. In particular, the `SameSite=strict` setting protects against cross site request forgery, which used to be a major concern with cookies.

Note that XSS remains a concern with cookies, though impact is reduced, since malicious code can only indirectly access the API message credential. Abuse of cookies is usually limited to the current window in the browser.

**WEB OAUTH BEST PRACTICES**

Therefore, the recommendation followed by most people who are diligent about browser security is the `Backend for Frontend` approach from [OAuth for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-backend-for-frontend-bff). The main problem this solves is to reduce the impact of an XSS exploit. The backend can attach a client secret, which also strengthens security a little.

**WEB ARCHITECTURE**

Yet for organizations who want to build JavaScript apps, this is an awkward requirement, since it requires an extra backend component that issues cookies. It is possible to issue the cookies from either the web side of the architecture or using a utility API. Either way it adds complexity.

**EXAMPLE IMPLEMENTATIONS**

Out of interest my [initial SPA example](https://authguidance.com/basicspa-overview/) calls the Cognito token endpoint from the browser, and my [final SPA example](https://authguidance.com/final-spa-overview/) instead does so via a utility API that issues cookies. Both approaches are possible, and you can run them both from a developer PC. The security design for your own app might depend on the sensitivity of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `/oauth2/token` endpoint supports both *authorization codes* ([authorization code grant flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow)) and *client secrets* ([client credentials flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow)).

> *grant_type*
>
> Must be `authorization_code` or `refresh_token` or `client_credentials`.

In the case of authorization codes (`/oauth2/authorize`), it's user-to-service authentication, and it takes place interactively. The authentication server will return an authorization code by redirecting the client through a `HTTP 302` redirect. The authorization code may then be used either by the client (e.g. SPA with PKCE challenge), or  by the backend itself to request an access token (`/oauth2/token`), allowing for delegated access to the user's resources protected by the resource server.

In the case of client secrets (`/oauth2/token`), it's service-to-service authentication, and it always takes place on the backend (*confidential client*) non-interactively, as the browser is not suited for protecting secrets (*public client*). Example architectures for this are the ['Backend For Frontend (BFF) Proxy'](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-15#name-backend-for-frontend-bff) or the ['Token-Mediating Backend'](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-15#name-token-mediating-backend).

The AWS Amplify libraries and Microsoft MSAL both support SPAs, which initiate the authorization code grant flow w/ PCKE and store tokens in the client (browser). This is considered secure, and used extensively by web apps.

Hence the following quote is slightly misleading & only makes sense in the context of the client credentials flow:

> The `/oauth2/token` endpoint only supports HTTPS POST. Your app makes
> requests to this endpoint directly, not through the user's browser.